# Converting CSV to JSON in a strange format

Tags: javascript, json, csv, webgl

I have a lot of geo's which I want to use in webgl globe.
The format for Webgl is

Sample for Googles .json file in their working webgl globe source    `[["1993",[long, lat,weight,long, lat,weight],["1994",[long, lat,weight,long, lat,weight,long, lat,weight,long, lat,weight]]]`

I've been looking for a way to convert this but i can't find a converter online.
Does anyone know where I can find a converter for this format or suggest a way to do this.

Sample of my data:

```
 - Year  Latitude   Longitude   Magnitude
 - 1995 -82.8627519 -135         0.11
 - 1995 -54.423199  3.413194     0.01
 - 1994 -53.08181   73.504158    0.01
 - 1994 -51.796253  -59.523613   0.04
 - 1993 -49.280366  69.348557    0.02
 - 1993 -41.4370868 147.1393767  0.18
```

Looking at this more, I think the json file Google are using is a nested json array of arrays. This

Comment: You know, that this is no JSON?

Comment: Hi Sirko, The working json file i downloaded would beg to differ. Is it possible it could be .json yet not be JSON?

Comment: Can you post the whole file somewhere, it will be easier to check the format

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to parse the data.
The **first step** is to save the data to a file.
For example:

```
Year  Latitude   Longitude   Magnitude
1995 -82.8627519 -135         0.11
1995 -54.423199  3.413194     0.01
1994 -53.08181   73.504158    0.01
1994 -51.796253  -59.523613   0.04
1993 -49.280366  69.348557    0.02
1993 -41.4370868 147.1393767  0.18
```

in raw.txt

The **second step** is to load and parse data.
With parsing there are a couple of things to keep in mind:

1. The raw data has an inconsistent number of white spaces separating values, so those need to be collapsed first so we can split a row/line by the space character. Luckily the data doesn't contains names containing spaces so we can use a RegEx like so `/\s{2,}/g`
2. We want to gather all the data pertaining to one year into a single list. One way is to use an array and continuously check if it has the year value already. Another is to simply use an Object/associative array/dictionary and not worry about any checks.
3. Once the data is correctly gathered in a object we pop it into a an array so it matches the format of the data being used.

Here's what I mean:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/globe/raw.txt', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var lines = xhr.responseText.split("\n");//split .txt file into lines
                var data = [];//prepare an array to hold the end result
                var dict = {};//use an Object/Dictionary to collapse data from same key/year
                for(var i = 1 ; i < lines.length; i++){//for each line
                    var line = lines[i].replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(' ');//collapse white spaces and split into an array of values
                    if( !dict[line[0]]) dict[line[0]] = [];//if there isn't an array to store that data yes, make one
                    dict[line[0]].push(parseFloat(line[1]));//append data into the coresponding key/year
                    dict[line[0]].push(parseFloat(line[2]));
                    dict[line[0]].push(parseFloat(line[3]));
                }
                for(var key in dict) data.push([key,dict[key]]);//at the end, loop through the object and populate an array
                console.log(data);
            }
          }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
```

so if you use something like this:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/globe/raw.txt', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var lines = xhr.responseText.split("\n");//split .txt file into lines
                var data = [];//prepare an array to hold the end result
                var dict = {};//use an Object/Dictionary to collapse data from same key/year
                for(var i = 1 ; i < lines.length; i++){//for each line
                    var line = lines[i].replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(' ');//collapse white spaces and split into an array of values
                    if( !dict[line[0]]) dict[line[0]] = [];//if there isn't an array to store that data yes, make one
                    dict[line[0]].push(parseFloat(line[1]));//append data into the coresponding key/year
                    dict[line[0]].push(parseFloat(line[2]));
                    dict[line[0]].push(parseFloat(line[3]));
                }
                for(var key in dict) data.push([key,dict[key]]);//at the end, loop through the object and populate an array
                window.data = data;
                for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                    globe.addData(data[i][1], {format: 'magnitude', name: data[i][0], animated: true});
                  }
                 globe.createPoints();
                 settime(globe,0)();
                 globe.animate();
            }
          }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
```

in the [WebGL Globe experiment](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/globe/) running on a server you will see your data.
[image: WebGL globe]